# write csv programatically the results of a function with lapply

Tags: r, function, loops, csv, lapply

I have the following code:

```
OD.viajes <- function(per) {

  require(ff)
  require(ETLUtils)
  require(RPostgreSQL)
  require(dplyr)
  require(stringr)

  con <- dbConnect("PostgreSQL", host = "11.111.111.11", user= "postgres", password="111111", dbname = "BASE_U_CHILE")
  qsql_par.ts <- "SELECT DISTINCT(cod_ts), cod_usu FROM par_ts;"
  qsql_par.viaje <- paste0(
    "SELECT COUNT(*), paraderosubida, paraderobajada, periodomediodeviaje FROM viajes201504_transparencia
     WHERE periodomediodeviaje = '",per,"' AND paraderosubida IN ('L-15-6-105-PO', 'L-15-6-115-PO', 'L-15-6-95-PO', 'L-16-14-100-NS')
     GROUP BY paraderosubida, paraderobajada, periodomediodeviaje;")

  par.ts <- read.dbi.ffdf(dbConnect.args = list(con), query = qsql_par.ts, VERBOSE=TRUE)  
  par.ts.sube <- as.data.frame(par.ts)
  names(par.ts.sube) <- c("par.sub", "cod.usu.sub")
  par.ts.baja <- as.data.frame(par.ts)
  names(par.ts.baja) <- c("par.baj", "cod.usu.baj")

  par.viaje <- read.dbi.ffdf(dbConnect.args = list(con), query =      qsql_par.viaje, VERBOSE=TRUE) 
  names(par.viaje) <- c("cuenta", "par.sub", "par.baj", "periodo")
  par.viaje <- as.data.frame(par.viaje)

  par.od.viaj <- left_join(par.viaje, par.ts.sube, by = "par.sub")
  par.od.viaj <- left_join(par.od.viaj, par.ts.baja, by = "par.baj")

  dbDisconnect(con)
  par.od.viaj

}

write.OD.viajes <- function(per) {
  write.csv(OD.viajes(per), paste0("par.od.viaj_",per,".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Now I want to export *.csv files depending of the values of the variable per, I'm guessing this can be done with lapply function, something like this:

```
lapply(my_list, function(x)write.OD.viajes(my_list[[x]], file = paste0(x, '.csv')))
```

But this form has an error (my functions are ok, the problem is the use of lapply). What kind of corrections must I do to my code?

I tried a For loop, but it takes much time, that's why I want to use lapply.

```
my_list <- list(c("04 - MANANA DOMINGO",
         "05 - MANANA SABADO",
         "05 - MEDIODIA DOMINGO",
         "12 - PRE NOCTURNO",
         "07 - TRANSICION DOMINGO NOCTURNO",
         "06 - PUNTA MEDIODIA SABADO",
         "04 - PUNTA MANANA",
         "02 - NOCTURNO SABADO",
         "03 - TRANSICION NOCTURNO"))
```

Comment: `purrr::walk()` was designed with this use-case in mind. I can't run your code but `purrr::walk(my_list, ~write.OD.viajes(., file=paste0(., '.csv')))` is one potential alternative

Comment: What is your error? A reproducible example would be helpful

Comment: What is the content of `my_list`? Does it have names? You are passing it in `lapply()` as a list of indices that are indexed on itself.

Comment: @Parfait they are 29 string chains , it has the following form : my_list <- list(c("pma", "pta", "ptpa", ...))

Comment: In fact , the elements on the list are the same used by per variable to produce each query in the previous functions.

Comment: Then just pass x itself not as an index and without file arg: `lapply(my_list, function(x) write.OD.viajes(x))` or better `lapply(my_list, write.OD.viajes)`

Comment: @MichaelChirico If I use lapply(my_list, function(x) write.OD.viajes(x)) the error is the following: Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
3: In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Called from: file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))